# Variable in Path to .htpasswd file in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, .htpasswd

Would it be possible to have the {HTTP_HOST} variable in this path?
Because my htaccess is used for multiple domains and I want to use different passwords for each domain!

```
AuthUserFile /usr/test/{HTTP_HOST}/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "My Files"
Require valid-user
```

**UPDATE:**
I tested the above code and it gives a 500 Internal Server Error (off course the AuthUserFile points to a directory that DOES exist on my server)

Comment: I don’t think that is easily possible. How are your different “domains” set up on the server – do they each have their own VirtualHost?

Comment: Multiple Domains point to one root-folder and are loading domainspecific language and config files, so I also want to use different Passwords for protected areas.